# Unlock All cells on PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

**SOLVED!!**

Found myself correct way to solve this problem . Use like `PHPExcel::getDefaultStyle()->getProtection()->setLocked(fals‌​e);` It's awesome :)

---

First of all, excel's default cell protection setting is (lock & visible).

I want to use lock some rows and unlock remaining rows.

I found ways to unlock specific cell and I try apply that to unlock all cells by some iterator.

But select all cells job is too heavy to execute iterator.

Is there something to change cell's default protect setting with PHPExcel?

Comment: Found myself correct way to solve this problem .

Use like `PHPExcel::getDefaultStyle()->getProtection()->setLocked(false);`

It's awesome :)