# How to protect individual cell using phpspreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I want to protect particular cell content from being amended. When I tried to protect whole sheet, no problem.

```php
$sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true)->setDeleteRows(true);
```

But, could not set protection for individual cell. I tried the following codes.

```php
$sheet->protectCellsByColumnAndRow(0, 1, 100, 100, 'asdf');
```

```php
$sheet->protectCells('A1','password',false);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the solution. First, enable the worksheet protection. Then, unlock all the cells by changing the default style of spreadsheet's protection. After that, lock the cell you want by specifying the cell's coordinate. The worksheet protection applied to locked cell only. So, the cell that you locked could not be edited anymore when you open that worksheet.

```php
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
$spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getProtection()->setLocked(false);
$spreadsheet->getStyle('A1')->getProtection()->setLocked(
    \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Protection::PROTECTION_PROTECTED
);
```

Helpful links:

- [Unlock All cells on PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376624/unlock-all-cells-on-phpexcel)
- [PHPExcel lock particular cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046207/phpexcel-lock-particular-cell)

Comment: getDefaultStyle()  is not found in Worksheet class

Comment: @PaulPreibisch It's on the Spreadsheet class.

Comment: Also, it's important to note that the locked cells can be easily unlocked with the click of a button in the Excel. One should also set a password if the cell should completely be protected: `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setPassword()`